# price from each item from listview into Total price is runing more than once,which is not the correct . How to run it once

Tags: flutter, dart

My listview total price code is runing more than once which is adding to the price variable again which is not the correct value ,how to prevent it from runing twice . As per my research my future builder is in build method ,if this is the problem then how to do it ,or any other suggestion would be great.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:restaurant_ui_kit/models/user.dart';
import 'package:restaurant_ui_kit/screens/checkout.dart';
import 'package:restaurant_ui_kit/util/database_helper.dart';

class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartScreenState createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<CartScreen> {
  var db = new DatabaseHelper();
  static int subTotal = 0;
  List _users = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 10.0, 0),

        child: FutureBuilder<List>(
          future: db.getAllUsers(),
          initialData: List(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                      final item = snapshot.data[position];

                      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
                        subTotal = subTotal +
                            int.parse(
                                User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).price);
                      }

                      print('toatl is $subTotal');

                      // get your item data here ...
                      return Dismissible(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        child: new Card(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          elevation: 2.0,
                          child: new ListTile(
                            leading: new CircleAvatar(
                              child: Text(
                                  "${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).name.substring(0, 1)}"),
                            ),
                            title: new Text(
                                "User: ${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).price}"),
                            subtitle: new Text(
                                "Id: ${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).id}"),
                            onTap: () => debugPrint(
                                "${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).id}"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        background: slideLeftBackground(),
                        confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
                          if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
                            final bool res = await showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    content: Text(
                                        "Are you sure you want to delete ${User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).name}?"),
                                    actions: <Widget>[
                                      FlatButton(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Cancel",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      FlatButton(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Delete",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          // TODO: Delete the item from DB etc..
                                          setState(() {
                                            // total();
                                            // print(position);
                                            if (position == 0) {
                                              //print('index 0 dai');
                                              db.deleteUser(User.fromMap(
                                                      snapshot.data[position])
                                                  .id);

                                              //snapshot.data.removeAt(position);
                                            } else {
                                              snapshot.data
                                                  .removeAt(--position);
                                              db.deleteUser(User.fromMap(
                                                      snapshot.data[position])
                                                  .id);
                                            }

                                            //print("removed");
                                            // print('mSubTotal $mSubTotal');
                                          });
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                });
                            return res;
                          }
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
          },
        ),


      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: "Checkout",
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Checkout();
              },
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_forward,
        ),
        heroTag: Object(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

Widget slideLeftBackground() {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Align(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.delete,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Text(
            " Delete",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    ),
  );
}
```

subTotal is printing like this in terminal the correctvalue is 500 because each item has price of 100 and there are 5 items but as you all know the last value is assigned to the variable

```
I/flutter ( 3885): Count : 5
I/flutter ( 3885): toatl is 500
I/flutter ( 3885): toatl is 1000
I/flutter ( 3885): toatl is 1500
I/flutter ( 3885): toatl is 2000
I/flutter ( 3885): toatl is 2500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sum and add values every time build method run. You can reset the subTotal every time or there is a shorter way to sum the values, you can try it; instead of using;

```
for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
  subTotal = subTotal +
      int.parse(
          User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).price);
}
```

just try this;

```
subTotal = snapshot.data.fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + int.tryParse(User.fromMap(item).price));
```

Comment: as per you suggestions i reset the value everytime the function is called , and it worked thanks .